# How to resolve strange behavior from some dart code

Tags: dart, flutter

I have some dart code in an interface to a Firebase Realtime Database that I need to handle setting up a stream for a particular path in my database and return all entries or use a pair of optional filter parameters to get only the required entries.

The method was originally just for the all entries requirement and works fine:

```
class _DatabaseStream<T> {
  _DatabaseStream(
      {String apiPath,
      DatabaseNodeParser<T> parser,
      String key = '',
      String filter = ''}) {
    AppDatabase _database = AppDatabase.db;

    FirebaseDatabase _firebaseDatabase = _database.firebaseDatabaseInstance;
    DatabaseReference _databaseReference =
        _firebaseDatabase.reference().child(apiPath);
    var eventStream = _databaseReference.onValue;
    stream = eventStream.map((event) => parser.parse(event));
  }

  Stream<T> stream;
}
```

However when I edit the code to process the optional filter parameters I get an exception from dart. This is the updated code:

```
class _DatabaseStream<T> {
  _DatabaseStream(
      {String apiPath,
      DatabaseNodeParser<T> parser,
      String key = '',
      String filter = ''}) {
    AppDatabase _database = AppDatabase.db;

    FirebaseDatabase _firebaseDatabase = _database.firebaseDatabaseInstance;
    DatabaseReference _databaseReference =
        _firebaseDatabase.reference().child(apiPath);
    var eventStream;
    if (filter == '') {
      eventStream = _databaseReference.onValue;
      stream = eventStream.map((event) => parser.parse(event));
    } else {
      // we have a filter
      Query query = _databaseReference.orderByChild(key).equalTo(filter);
      eventStream = query.onValue;
      stream = eventStream.map((event) => parser.parse(event));
    }
  }

  Stream<T> stream;
}
```

The exception reported is:

```
I/flutter (32750): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (32750): The following assertion was thrown building EggsPage(dirty, state: _EggsPageState#93899):
I/flutter (32750): type '_MapStream<Event, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<List<Egg>>'
I/flutter (32750):
I/flutter (32750): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (32750): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (32750): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (32750):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
```

Is this really a bug that I need to report, or is there some error in my updates to the method?

Comment: I do not know Firebase too much, but I already received this kind of message a lot of times. It's telling you that you are trying to cast an object to a wrong type (Map<Event, dynamic> == List<Egg>).  Take a look where you do this kind of cast in you code...

Comment: Yes, I understand the message, however, the SAME code is being used to instantiate this class in both cases. The second case throws the exception and I see no difference in the code I wrote.

Comment: Hey! I'm having the exact same issue, have you been able to resolve it?